# addEventListener won't be triggered at the first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load a js script when a button(in a React component) is clicked.
I use `webpack import` to load the JS file.
Not sure how come the `addEventListener` won't be triggered at the first click.

I add `cosole.log` for debugging. when clicking that button first time, will only get `TEST_1`.
And, if click that button second time, will get `TEST_2` and `TEST_3` as well.

**React Component snippet**

```
const Component = () => {

  const loadJS = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "od-survey" */ "./ol_od_survey.js");

  return (
    <>
          <button
            className={"button"}
            onClick={loadJS}
          >
            Click Me
          </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

**JS file snippet**

```
function(w, o) {
  "use strict";
    console.log("TEST_1");
    w.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("TEST_2");
      if ( event.target.textContent === "Click Me") {
        console.log("TEST_3");
        actionFunc();
      }
    });


    var actionFunc = function() {
      Do Someting Here
    }
     
})(window, window.OOo);
```

Click the button to load that JS file

Comment: Because you are basically adding listener while event is triggered, so the listener will be applied only after event (first click) is finished

Comment: @NikitaChayka any suggestion to reolve that?

Comment: What exactly is your end goal?

Comment: @NikitaChayka load that js script when click that button in React component.
And, in that js script, there is a actionFunc will be triggered a modal when that button is click.

These two tasks should happend at the same time.

Comment: So just execute code that you need in click handler manually. In this case in script after .addEvent… just call actionFunc(), it will get executed when script load first time

Comment: @NikitaChayka
I add `ref = useRef(null);` and `ref={ref} to button`
And revise `loadJS` function to 
  `const loadJS = () => {
    ref.current.click();
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "od-survey" */ "./ol_od_survey.js");
  };`

But it's not working and still need to click twice. Is there any I mistake?

Comment: You cannot do another click there, you need to call `actionFunc()` manually

Comment: @NikitaChayka, I'm so sorry. I really don't get it. Would you mind attach code as reference? Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments the reason why you need 2 click, because you are attaching your "loaded" `eventListener` within the first click, so it just cannot be triggered, only subsequent clicks will trigger that `listenet`.

Also, as discussed if what you need is to execute `actionFunc()` first time when script isn't loaded yet then you could just execute it manually on script load by adding call to `actionFunc()` at script end

```
function(w, o) {
  "use strict";
    console.log("TEST_1");
    w.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("TEST_2");
      if ( event.target.textContent === "Click Me") {
        console.log("TEST_3");
        actionFunc();
      }
    });


    var actionFunc = function() {
      Do Someting Here
    }

    //manually execute actionFunc on first load
    actionFunc(); 
})(window, window.OOo);
```

Other "hacky" way would be to use `ref` on button and trigger click on it **after** import finished `import(/* webpackChunkName: "od-survey" */ "./ol_od_survey.js").then(_ => btnRef.current.click());`